# How to get documents from Solr that are not older than 14 days

Tags: solr4

I have one field `posteddate` within a schema defined as

```
<fieldType name="date" 
           class="solr.TrieDateField" 
           precisionStep="0" 
           positionIncrementGap="0"/>
```

How can I get all records within 15 days from the posted date ie. current date should not be greater than 15 days from the posteddate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a range search according to https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Standard+Query+Parser

For example:

```
select?q=posteddate:[2013-01-01T00:00:00.00Z TO 2013-01-15T00:00:00.00Z]
```

- Square brackets [ ] denote an inclusive range query that matches
  values including the upper and lower bound.
- Curly brackets { } denote
  an exclusive range query that matches values between the upper and
  lower bounds, but excluding the upper and lower bounds themselves.